# How to get a filename without extension in Kotlin

Tags: io, kotlin

What is the best way to get the filename from a String or a File object, removing the extension?

Answer (score 18):

I found that creating a File object is a straightforward way to achieve this. No actual file will be created on disk. But take care that only the last extension will be removed:

```
File("myFile.txt").nameWithoutExtension
File("myFile.tar.gz").nameWithoutExtension
```

result:

> "myFile"
>
> "myFile.tar"

Comment: Be aware that `File` class does not ensure that the file really exists, so you might end up getting a name of a file that does not exist. Use `file.exists()` to check if the resource **really** exists or not

Answer (score 9):

I can not post this as comment, so I have to post this as separate answer.

Your solution will work, but seems like a little bit overkill. Implementation of this function simply calls `substringBeforeLast(".")` on filename, so I suggest to use this function. By default it will return exact same string, if string has no dot, but you can override this behaviour by providing second parameter.